# Is string subscript an associated index?

Tags: c++, string, indexing, subscript

> The subscript operator (**[]**) takes a std::string::size_type value.
>   The operator returns a reference to the character at the given
>   position. The value in the subscript is referred to as "a subscript" **pp93 ~ 94 C++ Primer 5ed.**

and

> A vector is a collection of objects, all of which have the same type. Evey object in the collection has an associated index, which gives
>   access to that object.**pp96 C++ Primer 5ed.**

**Question:**

Is string subscript an associated index? If not, what is the difference between the subscript of the std::string type and the associated index of the collection/vector?

Comment: According to [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), the function "[r]eturns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed." This is exactly the same as the subscript operator for the first excerpt, so I presume, yes, a string subscript is an associated index.

Comment: "associated index" is no official term, it merely refers to "the index that is associated with the element", this statement makes sense for a vector as well for a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think "index" as "the sequential number of an item," not "index" as "the lookup table in a book."

What they're saying about vectors is that the elements in them can be accessed through sequential numeric indices: `v[0]`, `v[1]`, etc.

The exact same holds for strings and the characters in them.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), the function:

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

According to [`std::basic_string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), the function:

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined.

Thus, they are pretty much the same thing. The term associated index means exactly what it sounds like; It is the index associated with the element, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The wording here is rather precise, but there is no real difference for these two simple cases. For both `string` and `vector`, `X[0]` denotes the first element of X. That is to say, 0 is the associated index of the first element of X, and 0 is also the argument to `operator[]`, aka the subscript.

To see an example that is not so simple, consider `std::string_view`. You can have a string_view of the 100th to 200th character of a string. Now `view[5]` has subscript 5, but it refers to the 105th character in the underlying string.